# Why I get different result when using inner join

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains the following columns; a, b, e  and another table, table2 that contains c,d. Both tables have a column `name`.

I made a query:

```
SELECT distinct a, b
from db.table
where e <>'65';
```

And I got say, 1885 records

Then, I needed more information from another table (c, d). I used inner join to get these additional information. The query becomes:

```
SELECT distinct a, b, c, d 
from db.table
inner join db.table2
on table.name=table2.name2
where e <>'65';
```

Now, I was expecting the same result but with additional columns (c, d). But I got a different number of results: 51144. Can any body explain please why the number increased while I just added more columns and did not change the condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISTINCT returns as the key word says, the distinct results from the select.

The fact that you are adding additional columns to the distinct select will possibly cause the distinct result set to be more rows. Lets have a look at an example

Distinct from

```
A   B
1   2
1   3
1   2
```

would be

```
A   B
1   2
1   3
```

but now adding additional columns to this, let say

```
A   B   C
1   2   1
1   3   2
1   2   3
```

will result in

```
A   B   C
1   2   1
1   3   2
1   2   3
```

Further more, your inner join can limit the result set, as inner join will only return values that are in both table1 and table2, so it a given value is present in table1, but not in table2 it will not be returned.

Or as was mentioned by @zerkms, if there were 2 keys defining the relationship between the 2 tables, you might get more that you expected.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is an evil operator :-) Instead of pretending there is no issues - it's is always better to just write **correct** query that doesn't return cartesian product

Comment: @zerkms, fully aggreed, but you are aware of 1-many joins, that is not a cartesian product/cross join?

Comment: when I perform 1:N entities query I don't expect the result set rows count to be the same as it was in the original 1-entity query :-)

Comment: OH! For some reason I *missed* the `distinct` part in the question queries (yes, in *both* of them) and thought you proposed to use it. Someone needs glasses... (or just finally go home after 8hrs workday)

Comment: @astander: Is there a way to avoid this issue ? If I connected the table 1:M. How can I get the result of the additional two columns without affecting the condition. What I need it to be distinct is only the value of (a).

Comment: If you wish to have a distinct selection, you have to make some decision regarding the other fields, maybe MAX, or SUM or MIN? But then you would rather use a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and practically it means that you likely need to be more precise on the join `ON` conditions.

The same result would be only possible if `table2` table contains one and only one record that matches condition `table.name=table2.name2` per each row from `table` table

Answer (score 1):

**INNER JOIN** will return only those result which match the same value of given column ( used in `ON` condition ) in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

What is surprising? You have 2 more columns added to your select statement and another table.

As an example distinct will apply to the 4 columns (a,b,c,d) not being repeated

If you're table is like this

```
A B C D E
1 2 1 1
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5
```

You're first statement will select distinct A,B which is only 1,2. The second statement will select 1,2,1,1 - 1,2,3,4 - 1,2,4,5 as long as it fulfills condition e <> 65

For the rest you need to use the **ON** to be more specific with regards to your select.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `DISTINCT` keyword **applies to the whole row**.

Say you have this results:

```
a       b        c         d
=====================================
1       1        1         1
1       1        3         2
1       1        4         2
1       2        5         2
1       2        6         6
1       3        1         1
```

if you apply `DISTINCT a, b`, it should result:

```
a       b     
==============
1       1             
1       2      
1       3
```

because two of the records were duplicate of `1,   1` . It will return all records if you say `DISTINCT a, b, c ,d`.

One other reason why your query returns multiple records is because it might be that the records of `tableA` has many corresponding matches on the records of `tableB`. Let's say on `tableA` you have only 1 record but in `tableB` that record has corresponding match of 5 records. If you try to join the tables, instead of 1 record from tableA, it should now return `5 rows` because of the matches.

Comment: How can I edit the query to convey the meaning of distinct(a) only ?? The b,c,d only needed to by displayed in the result as detail for the a. The only value that needs to be distinct is a.

Comment: you can wrap it in a subquery :D