# How to get more information about one distinct coulmn from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT distinct a, b, c, d 
FROM db.table
INNER JOIN db.table2
ON table.name=table2.name2
WHERE e <>'65';
```

The query select the values that are distinct in a,b,c,d. What I actually need is distinct `a` only. The rest of columns `b,c,d` I need them to provide more information about `a`. How can I perform this.
Knowing that the tables are connected as 1:N where the column `table2.name2` is a foreign key reference to table.name. i.e, table.name is unique value that can have more than corresponding records in table2.

What is the difference between two tables connected as 1:M with foreign key and two completely separate tables in terms of writing a query.

Comment: is this the same with [Why I get different result when using inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964278/why-i-get-different-result-when-using-inner-join)

Answer (score 1):

To achive this you need to use `GROUP BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`  in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT a,
       GROUP_CONCAT(b) AS b,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c) AS c,
       GROUP_CONCAT(d) AS d
FROM db.table
     INNER JOIN db.table2
        ON table.name=table2.name2
WHERE e <>'65'
GROUP BY a;
```